# Confuse about rule of Dangerous Method Bang

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Accordingly to this [style guides](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#dangerous-method-bang):

The names of potentially dangerous methods (i.e. methods that modify self or the arguments, exit! (doesn’t run the finalizers like exit does), etc) should end with an exclamation mark if there exists a safe version of that dangerous method.

Example:

```
# bad - there is no matching 'safe' method
class Person
  def update!
  end
end

# good
class Person
  def update
  end
end

# good
class Person
  def update!
  end

  def update
  end
end
```

Is it a bad practice to have a standalone `update!`? I have the following code:

```
class Metric < ApplicationRecord
  def analyse!
    res = Service.get_metrics
    update!(res)
  end
end
```

Should I rename the name of this method to `analyse` or create a `analyse` method:

```
class Metric < ApplicationRecord
  def analyse!
    res = Service.get_metrics
    update!(res)
  end

  def analyse
    analyse!
  rescue
    false
  end
end
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, as you quote, a stand alone `analyze!` is bad because "there is no matching 'safe' method". You should name the method `analyze` because the sample version of `analyze` you propose doesn't do anything meaningful except call `analyze!`.

Comment: There is at least one exception to that rule: the method [BasicObject#!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/BasicObject.html#method-i-21) (where `!true` is syntactic sugar for `true.!`). This method is neither dangerous nor has a non-bang version.

Comment: @CarySwoveland - Out of curiosity and recognizing there is at least one exception to the rule, would you recommend the OP follow the style guide or disregard it?

Comment: @jvillian: Neither. This is opinion-based, with arguments for each, and no objectively correct answer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland good catch, but I don't think the conventions for methods ending with `!`, `?`, or `=` apply to _operator methods_. Here `!` is used as a prefix denoting "not", e.g. `!true` (not true), `a != b` (not equal), `a !~ b` (not match).

Comment: @Amadan - There are numerous conventions for which there are no objectively correct answers. That's sort of the point of conventions. [Jörg W Mittag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2988/j%c3%b6rg-w-mittag), from whom I often learn a ton, provides a thorough discussion of at least one rationale for this convention. I also learn a ton from, [Cary Swoveland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256970/cary-swoveland). Which is why I asked Cary the question. But, thank you for volunteering an answer on Cary's behalf.

Comment: @jvillian, I do think the style guide is useful, in part because of its educational value. Whether one agrees or disagrees with certain of its guidelines, it's an interesting and informative read. Me, I pay no attention to it in writing code (and sometimes knowingly violate guidelines), as my main objective is to write code that I find pleasing. Being a Ruby hobbyist, I don't have worry about code shop considerations. I do think worker bees are well-advised to follow conventions as best they can, at least early in their careers: `thisVariableNameWorksButItMayNotInspireConfidence`.

Comment: @Stefan, I suffer from occasional bouts of pedanticophilia, but `BasicObject#!` *is* a garden-variety method that ends with an explanation mark. I will consider your thesis that the convention about method names ending with an exclamation mark does not apply to "operator methods" if you can provide me with Ruby's definition of an "operator" (which I do not think exists).

Comment: @CarySwoveland if we apply the conventions for regular method names to operators, `==` becomes an _assignment method_ because it ends with a `=`. And according to the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Method+Names), "For assignment methods, the return value is ignored and the arguments are returned instead"_. Obviously, `==` neither is an assignment method, nor does it return its argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bang is *always* used to mark the "more surprising" (I don't particularly like the definition that uses "dangerous") of a *pair* of methods that do the same (or almost same) thing in a slightly different manner.

In both of your cases, there is no second, less surprising, method, so in both your cases, you don't need and should not use a bang.

There are plenty of examples of methods that, e.g., mutate the receiver and don't have a bang:

- [`Array`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html)

  - [`Array#append`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-append)
  - [`Array#clear`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-clear)
  - [`Array#delete`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-delete)
  - [`Array#delete_at`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-delete_at)
  - [`Array#delete_if`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-delete_if)
  - [`Array#fill`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-fill)
  - [`Array#insert`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-insert)
  - [`Array#keep_if`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-keep_if)
  - [`Array#pop`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-pop)
  - [`Array#prepend`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-prepend)
  - [`Array#push`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-push)
  - [`Array#replace`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-replace)
  - [`Array#shift`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-shift)
  - [`Array#unshift`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-unshift)
- [`Hash`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html)

  - [`Hash#clear`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-clear)
  - [`Hash#delete`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-delete)
  - [`Hash#delete_if`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-delete_if)
  - [`Hash#keep_if`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-keep_if)
  - [`Hash#replace`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-replace)
  - [`Hash#rehash`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-rehash)
  - [`Hash#shift`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-shift)
  - [`Hash#store`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-store)
  - [`Hash#update`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-update)
- [`IO`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html)

  - Many methods in `IO` will in some way make changes to the I/O stream, such as advancing the file pointer (anything with `read`, `write`, `print`, or `put` in it, for example) or writing something to it (`print`, `puts`, anything with `write` in it).
- [`Module`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html)

  - Many methods in `Module` will in some way change the module; in fact, they would be pretty useless if they didn't! E.g. [`Module#alias_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-alias_method), [`Module#define_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-define_method), [`Module#attr`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-attr), [`Module#attr_reader`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-attr_reader), [`Module#attr_writer`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-attr_writer), [`Module#attr_accessor`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor) add methods to the module, and [`Module#prepend`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-prepend) and [`Module#include`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-include) modify the ancestry chain.
- [`Random`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Random.html)

  - Methods that return random values will change the internal state of the pseudo-random number generator: [`Random#bytes`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Random.html#method-i-bytes) and [`Random#rand`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Random.html#method-i-rand).
- [`String`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html)

  - [`String#clear`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-clear)
  - [`String#concat`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-concat)
  - [`String#force_encoding`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-force_encoding)
  - [`String#insert`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-insert)
  - [`String#prepend`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-prepend)
  - [`String#replace`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-replace)
  - [`String#setbyte`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-setbyte)
- [`Object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html)

  - [`Object#define_singleton_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-define_singleton_method)
  - [`Object#extend`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-extend)
  - [`Object#freeze`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-freeze)
  - [`Object#instance_variable_set`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set)
  - [`Object#remove_instance_variable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-remove_instance_variable)
  - [`Object#taint`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-taint)
  - [`Object#trust`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-trust)
  - [`Object#untaint`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-untaint)
  - [`Object#untrust`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-untrust)

These are only some of the methods that I can think of off the top of my head that mutate their receiver. There are also other "dangerous" / "surprising" methods that are dangerous or surprising in a different way than mutating their receiver which don't have a bang: [`Module#private`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-private), [`Module#protected`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-protected), and [`Module#public`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-public) modify the way *other things* work which are evaluated in the same scope, e.g. method definitions. [`String#intern`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-intern) and [`String#to_sym`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-to_sym) mutate the global symbol table. [`Kernel#load`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-load), [`Kernel#require`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-require), and [`Kernel#require_relative`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-require_relative) mutate `$LOADED_FEATURES`. Many [`Regexp`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html) methods modify the thread-local global pseudo-variables `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, `$4`, `$5`, `$6`, `$7`, `$8`, and `$9`.

Obviously, the whole point of writer methods such as attribute writers (e.g. `foo=`) and indexing writers (`[]=`) is to mutate the receiver. There are also plenty of operator methods that mutate the receiver (e.g. [`Array#<<`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C)). However, in all of these cases, it doesn't make sense to add a bang to the name.

There is also one operator method whose name *is* the bang, namely [`BasicObject#!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/BasicObject.html#method-i-21), but applying the rule about bang methods to this is obviously silly.

The! takeaway! is! that! bang! methods! should! only! be! used! for! marking! one! method! of! a! pair! if! you! use! bang! to! mark! every! potentially! unsafe! method! Ruby! would! get! very! annoying! to! read!

As a closing remark, I want to address a tiny part of your question (**bold** emphasis mine):

> The names of potentially dangerous methods (i.e. methods that modify self **or the arguments**, exit! (doesn’t run the finalizers like exit does), etc) should end with an exclamation mark if there exists a safe version of that dangerous method.

Methods should *never* mutate their arguments. Period. That is *so* surprising and dangerous, no amount of exclamation marks are warning enough.